# Collision detection

Tags: c#, collision-detection, monogame

So I've made my collision boxes visual (`Draw` method) and I saw that there were some problems with the boxes and I fixed them (x, y, length, width). They are now big enough.

This is the collision box inside my constructor for my `TileSprite` class:

```
public TileSprite(Texture2D collisionImage, Texture2D textureImage, Vector2 position, Point frameSize, Point currentFrame)
    : base (collisionImage, textureImage, position, frameSize, currentFrame)
{
    // Collision box (Rectangle)
    bCollisionRect = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, frameSize.X * 2, frameSize.Y * 2);
}
```

And this is the collision box for my `PlayerMovement` class. This collision box is written in the update method so it updates when the player moves:

```
collisionRect = new Rectangle((int)position.X + 4, (int)position.Y + 14, frameSize.X + 10, frameSize.Y + 20);
```

`TileSprite` and `PlayerMovement` have an abstract class in common, named `Sprite`.I have all my virtual methods for the sprites in `Sprite` and this is my `Collision` method:

```
public virtual void Collision (GameTime gameTime)
{
    // collisionRect is from PlayerMovement and bCollisionRect from TileSprite
    if(collisionRect.Intersects(bCollisionRect))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("collision");
    }
}
```

But my problem is, that there is no console output when the two collision boxes intersect. (Yes, I call the collision method.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of updating your object's Rectangle variable each frame, you should instead create a read-only Property for it:

```
public Rectangle Rectangle
{
    get { 
        return new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, frameSize.X * 2, frameSize.Y * 2); 
    }
}
```

Your player update method should look like:

```
public void Update(TileSprite[] TilesToCheck)
{
    //Move player
    ...

    //Check for collision
    Collision(TilesToCheck);
}
```

And then your Player's Collision function:

```
public virtual void Collision (TileSprite[] TilesToCheck)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < TilesToCheck.Length; i++)
    {
        if(Rectangle.Intersects(TilesToCheck[i].Rectangle))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("collision");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon! I will try this as soon as possible and will give you the feedback. One question though: my `GraphicsDevice` is still returning `null` (in my previous question). I updated the question a bit, could you maybe look at it again?

Comment: I managed to do this by changing one line of code but I will update my code with your code! (and I will delete the `DrawableGameComponent`)